# Controlling State from outside of a StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to understand the best practice for controlling a StatefulWidget's state outside of that Widgets State.

I have the following interface defined.

```
abstract class StartupView {
  Stream<String> get onAppSelected;

  set showActivity(bool activity);
  set message(String message);
}
```

I would like to create a StatefulWidget `StartupPage` that implements this interface. I expect the Widget to do the following:

1. When a button is pressed it would send an event over the `onAppSelected` stream. A controller would listen to this event and perform some action ( DB call, service request, etc ).
2. The controller can call `showActivity` or `set message` to have the view show progress with a message.

Because a Stateful Widget does not expose its State as a property, I don't know the best approach for accessing and modifying the State's attributes.

The way I would expect to use this would be something like this:

```
Widget createStartupPage() {
    var page = new StartupPage();
    page.onAppSelected.listen((app) {
      page.showActivity = true;
      //Do some work
      page.showActivity = false;
    });
  }
```

I've thought about instantiating the Widget by passing in the state I want it to return in `createState()` but that feels wrong.

Some background on why we have this approach: We currently have a Dart web application. For view-controller separation, testability, and forward-thinking towards Flutter, we decided that we would create an interface for every view in our application. This would allow a WebComponent or a Flutter Widget to implement this interface and leave all of the controller logic the same.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can expose the state's widget with a static method, a few of the flutter examples do it this way and I've started using it as well:

```
class StartupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static StartupPageState of(BuildContext context) => context.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<StartupPageState>());

  @override
  StartupPageState createState() => new StartupPageState();
}

class StartupPageState extends State<StartupPage> {
  ...
}
```

You can then access the state by calling `StartupPage.of(context).doSomething();`.

The caveat here is that you need to have a BuildContext with that page somewhere in its tree.

Comment: If this is a reasonable solution, would it also be reasonable to have the StatefulWidget store it's state in a property?

Comment: The problem there is that `createState()` is a lifecycle method called by flutter, so you shouldn't call it yourself and store the returned state.

Comment: The problem I see with this approach is that it would require that our generic controllers be part of the Widget tree which would go against our design goal of having them reusable on web. It seems like Flutter is forcing anything that needs to change state of a widget to be a widget itself.

Comment: @MatthewSmith have you found a solution to your code sharing or do you still need some pointers? :)

Comment: This strategy don't work. You can't see exposed state methods: `[dart] Static method 'myStaticMethod' can't be accessed through an instance. [instance_access_to_static_member]`

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano you are trying to access a static method through an instance. You have to call it through ClassName.staticMethodName.

Comment: does anyone know of any flutter examples that use this technique?

Comment: which context should be passed to `of`?

Comment: Hi, 'TypeMatcher' is deprecated. Could you update with the latest update?

Comment: Use this method context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MenuDashboardPageState>();

Answer (score 144):

There are multiple ways to interact with other stateful widgets.

**1. findAncestorStateOfType**

The first and most straightforward is through `context.findAncestorStateOfType` method.

Usually wrapped in a static method of the `Stateful` subclass like this :

```
class MyState extends StatefulWidget {
  static of(BuildContext context, {bool root = false}) => root
      ? context.findRootAncestorStateOfType<_MyStateState>()
      : context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyStateState>();

  @override
  _MyStateState createState() => _MyStateState();
}

class _MyStateState extends State<MyState> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

This is how `Navigator` works for example.

Pro:

- Easiest solution

Con:

- Tempted to access `State` properties or manually call `setState`
- Requires to expose `State` subclass

Don't use this method when you want to access a variable. As your widget may not reload when that variable change.

**2. Listenable, Stream and/or InheritedWidget**

Sometimes instead of a method, you may want to access some properties. The thing is, you most likely want your widgets to update whenever that value changes over time.

In this situation, dart offer `Stream` and `Sink`. And flutter adds on the top of it `InheritedWidget`  and `Listenable` such as `ValueNotifier`. They all do relatively the same thing: subscribing to a value change event when coupled with a `StreamBuilder`/`context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType`/`AnimatedBuilder`.

This is the go-to solution when you want your `State` to expose some properties. I won't cover all the possibilities but here's a small example using `InheritedWidget` :

First, we have an `InheritedWidget` that expose a `count` :

```
class Count extends InheritedWidget {
  static of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<Count>();

  final int count;

  Count({Key key, @required Widget child, @required this.count})
      : assert(count != null),
        super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(Count oldWidget) {
    return this.count != oldWidget.count;
  }
}
```

Then we have our `State` that instantiate this `InheritedWidget`

```
class _MyStateState extends State<MyState> {
  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Count(
      count: count,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: CountBody(),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              count++;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Finally, we have our `CountBody` that fetch this exposed `count`

```
class CountBody extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(Count.of(context).count.toString()),
    );
  }
}
```

Pros:

- More performant than `findAncestorStateOfType`
- Stream alternative is dart only (works with web) and is strongly integrated in the language (keywords such as `await for` or `async*`)
- Automic reload of the children when the value change

Cons:

- More boilerplate
- Stream can be complicated

**3. Notifications**

Instead of directly calling methods on `State`, you can send a `Notification` from your widget. And make `State` subscribe to these notifications.

An example of `Notification` would be :

```
class MyNotification extends Notification {
  final String title;

  const MyNotification({this.title});
}
```

To dispatch the notification simply call `dispatch(context)` on your notification instance and it will bubble up.

```
MyNotification(title: "Foo")..dispatch(context)
```

> Note: you need put above line of code **inside a class**, otherwise no context, can NOT call notification.

Any given widget can listen to notifications dispatched by their children using `NotificationListener<T>` :

```
class _MyStateState extends State<MyState> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<MyNotification>(
      onNotification: onTitlePush,
      child: Container(),
    );
  }

  bool onTitlePush(MyNotification notification) {
    print("New item ${notification.title}");
    // true meaning processed, no following notification bubbling.
    return true;
  }
}
```

An example would be `Scrollable`, which can dispatch `ScrollNotification` including start/end/overscroll. Then used by `Scrollbar` to know scroll information without having access to `ScrollController`

Pros:

- Cool reactive API. We don't directly do stuff on `State`. It's `State` that subscribes to events triggered by its children
- More than one widget can subscribe to that same notification
- Prevents children from accessing unwanted `State` properties

Cons:

- May not fit your use-case
- Requires more boilerplate

Comment: Thanks, The first method works very well. I used this to navigate from a sub widget to a different screen while not using the traditional material naviagtion stack ...

Comment: ancestorStateOfType deprecated

Comment: Just to clarify for quick readers (like me) the answer above uses at this date findAncestorStateOfType which is not deprecated. ancestorStateOfType is indeed deprecated.

Answer (score 33):

There is another common used approach to have access to State's properties/methods:

```
class StartupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  StartupPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  StartupPageState createState() => StartupPageState();
}

// Make class public!
class StartupPageState extends State<StartupPage> {
  int someStateProperty;

  void someStateMethod() {}
}

// Somewhere where inside class where `StartupPage` will be used
final startupPageKey = GlobalKey<StartupPageState>();

// Somewhere where the `StartupPage` will be opened
final startupPage = StartupPage(key: startupPageKey);
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => startupPage);

// Somewhere where you need have access to state
startupPageKey.currentState.someStateProperty = 1;
startupPageKey.currentState.someStateMethod();
```

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me when trying to access the state of a screen I had pushed using `Navigator.push()`, it always returned `null`. This worked like a charm!

Comment: Unlike the accepted answer, this also works when you have multiple instances of the same widget on a screen. Each one's got its own key here!

Comment: Where is the context coming from?

Answer (score 10):

I do:

```
class StartupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  StartupPageState state;

  @override
  StartupPageState createState() {
    this.state = new StartupPageState();

    return this.state;
  }
}

class DetectedAnimationState extends State<DetectedAnimation> {
```

And outside just `startupPage.state`

Comment: StatefulWidget is supposed to be inmutable, so declaring the non-final property state is not correct (and will cause a warning).

Answer (score 3):

While trying to solve a similar problem, I discovered that `ancestorStateOfType()` and `TypeMatcher` have been deprecated. Instead, one has to use `findAncestorStateOfType()`. However as per the documentation, "calling this method is relatively expensive". The documentation for the `findAncestorStateOfType()` method can be found [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/findAncestorWidgetOfExactType.html).

In any case, to use `findAncestorStateOfType()`, the following can be implemented (this is a modification of the correct answer using the `findAncestorStateOfType()` method):

```
class StartupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static _StartupPageState of(BuildContext context) => context.findAncestorStateOfType<_StartupPageState>();

  @override
  _StartupPageState createState() => new _StartupPageState();
}

class _StartupPageState extends State<StartupPage> {
  ...
}
```

The state can be accessed in the same way as described in the correct answer (using `StartupPage.of(context).yourFunction()`). I wanted to update the post with the new method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **eventify**

> This library provide mechanism to register for event notifications with emitter
>   or publisher and get notified in the event of an event.

You can do something like:

```
// Import the library
import 'package:eventify/eventify.dart';
final EventEmitter emitter = new EventEmitter();

var controlNumber = 50;

List<Widget> buttonsGenerator() {
    final List<Widget> buttons = new List<Widget>();
    for (var i = 0; i < controlNumber; i++) {
        widgets.add(new MaterialButton(
                  // Generate 10 Buttons afterwards
                  onPressed: () {
                    controlNumber = 10;
                    emitter.emit("updateButtonsList", null, "");
                  },
                );
    }
}

class AState extends State<ofYourWidget> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        List<Widget> buttons_list = buttonsGenerator();
        emitter.on('updateButtonsList', null, (event, event_context) {
            setState(() {
                buttons_list = buttonsGenerator();
            });
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

I can't think of anything which can't be achieved by event driven programming. You are limitless!

> "Freedom cannot be bestowed — it must be achieved."
>   - Elbert Hubbard

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered lifting the state to the parent widget? It is a common, though less ideal than Redux, way to manage state in React as far as I know, and this [repository](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_architecture_samples/tree/master/vanilla) shows how to apply the concept to a Flutter app.

Comment: Link is broken.