# How to Set/Update State of StatefulWidget from other StatefulWidget in Flutter?

Tags: state, flutter

1. For Example in the below code plus button works and able to update
   the text but the minus button does not.
2. But if we press FloatingActionButton then the State is refreshed .
3. The minus button is changing the value of the variable but not
   updating the state of parent widget .

[image]

here is code .....

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

int number;

EdgeInsets globalMargin = const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 20.0);
TextStyle textStyle = const TextStyle(
  fontSize: 100.0,
  color: Colors.black,
);

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    number = number ?? 0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text(
            number.toString(),
            style: textStyle,
          ),
          new GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: <Widget>[
              new InkResponse(
                child: new Container(
                    margin: globalMargin,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: new Center(
                      child: new Text(
                        "+",
                        style: textStyle,
                      ),
                    )),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    number = number + 1;
                  });
                },
              ),
              new Sub(),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {});
        },
        child: new Icon(Icons.update),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Sub extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SubState createState() => new _SubState();
}

class _SubState extends State<Sub> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new InkResponse(
      child: new Container(
          margin: globalMargin,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: new Center(
            child: new Text(
              "-",
              style: textStyle,
            ),
          )),
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          number = number - 1;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I really like [scoped_model](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scoped_model) to control app-wide data.

Comment: have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491860/flutter-how-to-correctly-use-an-inherited-widget/49492495#49492495

Comment: You can use Inherited Widget

Comment: Nobody explained why is this happening so here it is in simple words: The "Sub" widget when calls "setState()" it will trigger an update for its (own) state and not for parent's state while the "+" or the floating action "setState()" trigger the update on parent's state. And until parent's state is not changed no visual change will be visible. Knowing this you helps find/pick a solution.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**Old / Not recommended / Failed solutions**:

1. Solution 1: Create a global instance of `_MyHomePageState`. Use this instance in `_SubState` as `_myHomePageState.setState`
2. Solution 2: No need to create a global instance. Instead, just pass the parent instance to the child widget
3. Solution 3: Passing a callback from parent widget to child widget to update state of parent widget from child widget

#### **Best Solution**: use the package [stream_mixin](https://pub.dev/packages/stream_mixin)

##### As of Feb '23

```
class Counter with StreamMixin<int> { // CODE TO NOTICE
  Counter._();
  static Counter instance = Counter._();

  increment() {
    update((lastUpdate ?? 0) + 1);
  }

  decrement() {
    update((lastUpdate ?? 0) - 1);
  }
}



class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('SO Help'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder<int>( // CODE TO NOTICE
            initialData: 0,
            stream: Counter.instance.onChange,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
            },
          ),
          GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: <Widget>[
              InkResponse(
                onTap: Counter.instance.increment, // CODE TO NOTICE
                child: const Text("+"),
              ),
              const Sub(),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Sub extends StatelessWidget {
  const Sub({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkResponse(
      onTap: Counter.instance.decrement, // CODE TO NOTICE
      child: const Text("-"),
    );
  }
}
```

##### Observe that:

1. I'm using `StatelessWidget`, which will increase the performance. (You may choose to use StatefulWidget depending on your requirements
2. Instead of `StatefulWidget` I'm using `StreamBuilder`, which will update only the `Text` widget inside the `SteamBuilder`. Unlike `setState()` updates the whole app
3. The logic is separated from UI

Comment: Works but bad. At least, use things such as `context.ancestorStateOfType`

Comment: @RémiRousselet can you please give an example of how to use it?

Comment: using this "_myHomePageState" throws error calling it undefined but "myHomePageState" doesn't, maybe variables need to be in camelCase and can't have an underscore in front of them

Comment: @KeshavAdityaR.P I have updated the code, please check. In dart underscore is to represent objects as private, if you with you can remove underscores.

Comment: This does not work if the child isn't in the same file as one would not have access to the `_state` class of the parent.

Comment: Remove underscore (`_`) and make life easy.

Comment: Instead of '_MyHomePageState' I believe you could also just do 'State'

Comment: Edit : I see why '_MyHomePageState' has to be passed into 'Sub' as the 'parent' as 'Sub' has to know about 'number'.  I wonder if there is a way to create a base class so I can reuse the same child 'Sub' across several parent pages (ie/ '_MyHomePageStateA' and '_MyHomePageStateB' and I would be passing in '_MyHomePageStateBase' into 'Sub'

Comment: @RémiRousselet ancestorStateOfType method was deprecated after v1.12.1.
Use `findAncestorStateOfType` instead https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/findAncestorStateOfType.html

Comment: Is this also possible with the sub being a StatefulWidget?

Comment: @RémiRousselet this link explicitly says that is better to use a callback.

Comment: @RémiRousselet I agree that using a callback is a better solution. Updated the answer accordingly. 

Answer (score 251):

**1.On Child Widget : add parameter Function paramter**

```dart
class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function() notifyParent;
  ChildWidget({Key key, @required this.notifyParent}) : super(key: key);
}
```

**2.On Parent Widget : create a Function for the child to callback**

```dart
refresh() {
  setState(() {});
}
```

**3.On Parent Widget : pass parentFunction to Child Widget**

```
new ChildWidget( notifyParent: refresh );
```

**4.On Child Widget : call the Parent Function**

```dart
  widget.notifyParent();
```

Comment: How I can do the reverse. I want to update child from Parent

Comment: @CodeGeek You can pass as property to child

Comment: What if the child is a statefull widget and I want to update it  from parent?

Comment: @sp4zRx store a refrance to the child and call a publice method on it

Comment: @MohamedElrashid how can we pass an argument from child to parent?

Comment: @Farhana refresh(argument1,argument1) {etState(() {});} | widget.notifyParent(1,2);

Comment: Is this "the supposed" solution? is this what the flutter team used? I smell trouble in that code. Or maybe just my nose too sensitive :D

Comment: @nafsaka hi ❤ if you have a better answer please add new answer , or ask the flutter team to add one you can open an issue on github,  if don't know how I'm more than happy to do it for you 

Comment: @CodeGeek were you able to get the solution? I have some data that keeps changing in the parent that I want to update in the bottom sheet component bottom sheet.which is also satefulwidget. I am able to get the update to the Bottom sheet stateful widget from there i am not able to update to the State class. Even though if i try to update it using some instance of state clas and calling methods inside state class and try to setState, I am getting the fallowing error: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

Comment: For those of you who want to `pass` values to child widget, you can create `ValueNotifier` in parent widget, and pass it to the child widget. In your child widget, utilize `ValueListenableBuilder` to build layouts.

Comment: can u help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61665353/widget-value-not-updating

Comment: if you still have an issue please update ```final Function() notifyParent;``` to ```final Function notifyParent;```

Comment: @CodeGeek Please create a new post for "How I can do the reverse. I want to update a child from the parent" and send the link.

Comment: @MohamedElrashid where did you get the `setState(() {});` it says `it's not declared` seems like flutter don't know what the `setState` is.

Comment: Hello, so how can I use setState in one ChildWidget from another ChildWidget?

Comment: Spent a couple of hours on a solution like this and still didn't get it to work - frustrating!  Your solution seemed unlikely at that point and voila! it worked - thank you!

Answer (score 123):

**Screenshot (Parent to child, Child to parent):**

[image]

This examples shows calling a method

1. Defined in Child widget from Parent widget.
2. Defined in Parent widget from Child widget.

---

**Code:**

```dart
class ParentPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<ChildPageState> _key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Parent")),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.grey,
                width: double.infinity,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text("Call method in child"),
                  onPressed: () => _key.currentState!.methodInChild(), // calls method in child
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Text("Above = Parent\nBelow = Child"),
            Expanded(
              child: ChildPage(
                key: _key,
                function: methodInParent,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  methodInParent() => Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Method called in parent", gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER);
}

class ChildPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback function;

  ChildPage({Key? key, required this.function}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ChildPageState createState() => ChildPageState();
}

class ChildPageState extends State<ChildPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.teal,
      width: double.infinity,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text("Call method in parent"),
        onPressed: () => widget.function(), // calls method in parent
      ),
    );
  }

  methodInChild() => Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Method called in child");
}
```

Comment: How to call if my "_ChildPageState" in other class ?

Comment: remove _ from _ChildPageState, 
an underscore _ means that the class is private.

Comment: I like this approach, 1 more thing to add is to take care of _key.currentState and check if it is not null.

Comment: how to do this with multiple children ? , isn't using GlobalKey() expensive on the device ?

Answer (score 20):

I would like to extend Mohamed Elrashid answer, in case you require to **pass a variable from the child widget to the parent widget**

*On child widget:*

```
class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function() notifyParent;
  ChildWidget({Key key, @required this.notifyParent}) : super(key: key);
}
```

*On parent widget*

```
void refresh(dynamic childValue) {
  setState(() {
    _parentVariable = childValue;
  });
}
```

*On parent widget: pass the function above to the child widget*

```
new ChildWidget( notifyParent: refresh );
```

*On child widget: call the parent function with any variable from the the child widget*

```
widget.notifyParent(childVariable);
```

Comment: I tried your method, however I get the warning on the `widget.notifyParent(childVariable);` line, saying: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.

Comment: It should work. Probably you have an issue on the second part `void refresh()`. Still im not a big fan of this approach, the code is prone to errors. Good luck!

Comment: @rb2030 check it now , you should add dynamic variable in function

Comment: @evals, please check again as your edit is not correct. As i have said above on my other comment, passing data to parent widget is NOT the way to work on with Flutter and should be avoided. Good luck.

Comment: @AlvinKonda well passing data worked with me, what never worked is your answer, thanks anyway :)

Comment: @AlvinKonda well passing data worked with me, what never worked is your answer, thanks anyway :)

Comment: The argument type 'void Function(dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function()

Comment: changing Function() notifyParent to Function notifyParent works.

Answer (score 9):

Old one but I would add my answer as per my findings:

```
var ancestralState = context.findAncestorStateOfType<ParentState>();
      ancestralState.setState(() {
        // here you can access public vars and update state.
        ...
      });
```

Answer (score 7):

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  int selectedIndex = 0;

   void setSelectedIndex(int index){
     setState(() {
      selectedIndex = index;
     });
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  TestPageState createState() => TestPageState();
}

class TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return  GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){

                        final HomePageState state = context.findAncestorStateOfType<HomePageState>();

                        state.setSelectedIndex(4);

                      },
                    child: Container(
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        color: Colors.green
              )
     );
  }

}
```

Comment: Please provide some context to your answer. It helps the other visitors to the question to understand your approach easily.

Answer (score 5):

**Here is the solution which worked for me.**

**OUTPUT:**
State of Cart Widget is updated, upon addition of items.

[image]

Create a `globalKey` for the widget you want to update by calling the `trigger from anywhere`

```
final GlobalKey<CartWidgetState> cartKey = GlobalKey();
```

Make sure it's saved in a file have global access such that, it can be accessed from anywhere.
I save it in globalClass where is save commonly used variables through the app's state.

```
class CartWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  CartWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  CartWidgetState createState() => CartWidgetState();
}

class CartWidgetState extends State<CartWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //return your widget
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Call your widget from some other class.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  HomeScreen ({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  HomeScreenState createState() => HomeScreen State();
}

class HomeScreen State extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
              children:[
                 ChildScreen(), 
                 CartWidget(key:cartKey)
              ]
            );
  }
}



class ChildScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  ChildScreen ({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  ChildScreenState createState() => ChildScreen State();
}

class ChildScreen State extends State<ChildScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
              onTap: (){
                // This will update the state of your inherited widget/ class
                if (cartKey.currentState != null)
                    cartKey.currentState.setState(() {});
              },
              child: Text("Update The State of external Widget"),
           );
  }
}
```

Comment: Passing defined Global defined key to variable key of StatefulWidget works for me.

Comment: I don't see any usage of `GlobalKey` in your snippets...

Answer (score 4):

Although most of these previous answers will work, I suggest you explore the provider or BloC architectures, both of which have been recommended by Google.

In short, the latter will create a stream that reports to widgets in the widget tree whenever a change in the state happens and it updates all relevant views regardless of where it is updated from.

Here is a good overview you can read to learn more about the subject: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/

Comment: Or, You can use event-driven architecture. Easiest. Why can't we use **eventify**? Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46057353/controlling-state-from-outside-of-a-statefulwidget/60533386#60533386answer-60533386

Comment: It would be nice to have an example of this, all these solutions seem overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are wanting to pass a variable back and forth between child and parent without the use of third-party libraries, here is an example I wrote with two counter buttons. Granted, I don't know if this is best practice, but I wanted to provide the simplest answer I could create:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ParentWid(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ParentWid extends StatefulWidget {  
  @override
  State<ParentWid> createState() => _ParentWidState();
}

class _ParentWidState extends State<ParentWid> {
  int counter = 0;
  
  void refresh(int childValue) {
    setState(() {
      counter = childValue;
    });
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children:[
       IconButton(
       onPressed: () {
         setState(() {
            counter++;
         });
       },
       icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      ChildWid(counter, refresh)
    ]);
  }
}

class ChildWid extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(int) notifyParent;
  final int? counter;
  const ChildWid(this.counter, this.notifyParent);

  @override
  State<ChildWid> createState() => _ChildWidState();
}

class _ChildWidState extends State<ChildWid> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children:[
      Text(
        'Current Counter ${widget.counter ?? 0}',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
      ),
      IconButton(
       onPressed: () {
         int counterHolder = widget.counter ?? 0;
         counterHolder++;
         widget.notifyParent(counterHolder);
       },
       icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little unorthodox, but it works: you keep state references of ***unrelated*** widgets in a common object and call them accordingly:

```
class Fuzz {
  State<A>? a;
  State<B>? b;
  int c = 0;
}



class A extends StatefulWidget {
  A(this.fuzz, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  Fuzz fuzz;
  @override
  State<A> createState() => _AState();
}

class _AState extends State<A> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.fuzz.a = this;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: TextButton(
      child: Text("More fuzz (${widget.fuzz.c})"),
      onPressed: () {
        widget.fuzz.b?.setState(() {
          widget.fuzz.c++;
        });
      },
    ));
  }
}

class B extends StatefulWidget {
  B(this.fuzz, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  Fuzz fuzz;
  @override
  State<B> createState() => _BState();
}

class _BState extends State<B> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.fuzz.b = this;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: TextButton(
      child: Text("Less fuzz (${widget.fuzz.c})"),
      onPressed: () {
        widget.fuzz.a?.setState(() {
          widget.fuzz.c--;
        });
      },
    ));
  }
}

 class TestView extends StatelessWidget {
  TestView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var fuzz = Fuzz();
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: Center(
            child: Row(
          children: [Expanded(child: A(fuzz)), Expanded(child: B(fuzz))],
        )));
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Why would you use a global variable & **initstate()** for this example?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

// const int number=0;

// EdgeInsets globalMargin = const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 20.0);
EdgeInsets globalEdgeFromLTRB = const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100, 0, 100, 0);
TextStyle textStyle = const TextStyle(
  fontSize: 100.0,
  color: Colors.black,
);

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  
  final String title;  

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  _MyHomePageState();
  int numberValue = 0;

  // @override
  // void initState() {
  //   super.initState();
  //   numberValue = numberValue;
  // }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(             
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              numberValue.toString(),
              style: textStyle,
            ),
            GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              children: <Widget>[              
                InkResponse(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: globalEdgeFromLTRB, //globalMargin,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "+",
                          style: textStyle,
                        ),
                      )),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      numberValue++;
                    });
                  },
                ),                          
                InkResponse(
                  child: Container(
                      margin: globalEdgeFromLTRB, // globalMargin,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "-",
                          style: textStyle,
                        ),
                      )),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      numberValue--;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
           numberValue = 0;
          });
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.update),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```