# How to access Provided (Provider.of()) value inside showModalBottomSheet?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-provider

I have a FloatingActionButton inside a widget tree which has a `BlocProvider` from [flutter_bloc](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/tree/master/packages/flutter_bloc). Something like this:

```
BlocProvider(
  builder: (context) {
    SomeBloc someBloc = SomeBloc();
    someBloc.dispatch(SomeEvent());

    return someBloc;
  },
  child: Scaffold(
    body: ...
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: _openFilterSchedule,
      child: Icon(Icons.filter_list),
    ),
  )
);
```

Which opens a modal bottom sheet:

```
void _openFilterSchedule() {
    showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return TheBottomSheet();
      },
    );
  }
```

I am trying to access `SomeBloc` using `BlocProvider.of<SomeBloc>(context)` inside `TheBottomSheet` but I get the following error:

```
BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type SomeBloc.
```

I have tried to use the solution described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56533611/2457045 but only works for `BottomSheet` and not `ModalBottomSheet`.

---

Note: This is not restricted to `BlocProvider` or `flutter_bloc`. Any Provider from the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package has the same behaviour.

How can I access `BlocProvider.of<SomeBloc>(context)` inside the `showModalBottomSheet`?

In case it's not possible to do that, how to adapt https://stackoverflow.com/a/56533611/2457045 solution to Modal Bottom Sheet?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

InheritedWidgets, and therefore Providers, are scoped to the widget tree. They cannot be accessed outside of that tree.

The thing is, using `showDialog` and similar functions, the dialog is located in a different widget tree – which may not have access to the desired provider.

It is therefore necessary to add the desired providers in that new widget tree:

```dart
void myShowDialog() {
  final myModel = Provider.of<MyModel>(context, listen: false);
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) {
      return Provider.value(value: myModel, child: SomeDialog());
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Is there anything to worry with this implementation? It seem strange provide 2 time.

Comment: @FlutterFirebase no. It's totally logical and desired

Comment: But is the 2 provider different? For example, is same variable access in both provider? I am implement now and it seem if I call method from new provider this is not notifylisteners in other widget tree

Comment: @FlutterFirebase you have to use the `.value` constructor, by passing it the existing variable.

Comment: If I do this it show `Unhandled Exception: Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Model> above this Page Widget`

Comment: it doesn't work for me, it says that the provider is called before it disposed, it seems that we have to add the provider in the top of material app as the modal bottom sheet is in a separate widget tree under material app directly
as stated in second answer

Comment: How to access provider value inside SomeDialog() widget ?

Comment: Awesome!!
I think it has a same pattern to BLoC so implemented it as well

final blocValue = BlocProvider.of<EcommerceBloc>(context, listen: false);
then on builder return BlocProvider.value(value: blocValue, child: const MyWidget());

Thanks man, i've been looking for this way quite long

Answer (score 14):

**Provider in `showModalBottomSheet` (Bottom-Sheet)**

```
void myBottomSheet() {
  final myModel = Provider.of<MyModel>(context, listen: false);
  showModalBottomShee(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) {
      return ListenableProvider.value(
        value: myModel,
        child: Text(myModel.txtValue),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the solution if you want to listen to state changes in the bottom sheet.

Comment: Great! Thank you. This IS the solution.

Answer (score 7):

You need move Provider to top layer(MaterialApp)

According to picture, Dialog widget is under MaterialApp, so this is why you using wrong context

[image]

Comment: Correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

wrap your whole child widget inside the consumer.

```dart
void myShowDialog() {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: Consumer<MyModel>(
        builder: (context, value, builder) {
        retuen widget(); 
      }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split Scaffold widget and its children, to another StatefulWidget

**From single Widget**

```dart
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      builder: (context) {
        SomeBloc someBloc = SomeBloc();
        someBloc.dispatch(SomeEvent());
        return someBloc;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: ...
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _openFilterSchedule,
          child: Icon(Icons.filter_list),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**Splitted into these two widget**

```dart
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      builder: (context) {
        SomeBloc someBloc = SomeBloc();
        someBloc.dispatch(SomeEvent());
        return someBloc;
      },
      child: Screen(),
    );
  }
}
```

and ..

```dart
class Screen extends StatelessWidget {

  void _openFilterSchedule() {
    showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return TheBottomSheet();
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ...
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _openFilterSchedule,
        child: Icon(Icons.filter_list),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I had to change `Screen` to `Stateful` in order to use showModalBottomSheet, but it does not work. Same error is throwed inside `TheBottomSheet`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, Just return your showModalBottomSheet with a StatefulBuilder and use the context of your modalsheet builder to pass to your provider. a snippet of my code below:

```
Future<Widget> showModal(int qty, Product product) async {
    return await showModalBottomSheet(
        isScrollControlled: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
          return StatefulBuilder(builder: (ctx, state) {
             return Container(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                             Product prod = Product(product.id, 
                                         product.sku, product.name, qty);
                             Provider.of<CartProvider>(ctx, listen: 
                                        false).addCart(prod);}),);
    }
  }
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not finding a clear explanation of adding multiple provided values, I thought I'd share here for reference.

```
   await showMobileModals(
    isDismissible: false,
    context: context,
    child: MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider.value(
          value: provided_one,
        ),
        Provider.value(
          value: provided_two,
        ),
        Provider.value(
          value: provided_three,
        ),
      ],
      child: Container(),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `ChangeNotifierProvider` from [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) and used `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` in the **bottomsheet**.

> **NOTE:**
> It's important to make sure to use the **provider's builder *context***:
> `builder: (context, _) {}`

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (context) => MyProvider(),
  builder: (context, _) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ...
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _openFilterSchedule(context),
        child: Icon(Icons.filter_list),
      ),
    ),
  },
);
```

The bottom sheet:

```dart
void _openFilterSchedule(BuildCOntext context) {
  showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (_) {
      return ChangeNotifierProvider<MyProvider>.value(
        value: context.watch<MyProvider>(),
        builder: (context, _) {
          final List<String> sampleDataToWatch =
              context.watch<MyProvider>().myData;

          if (sampleDataToWatch.isEmpty) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            return Column(
              children: sampleDataToWatch.map((name) => Text(name)).toList(),
            );
          }
        },
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Just a sample provider and the future changes:

```dart
class MyProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<String> myData = [];

  MyProvider() {
    loadNames();
  }

  void loadNames() {
    Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 3),
      () {
        myData.addAll(['John', 'Maria', 'Lewis', 'Danny']);
        notifyListeners();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**TLDR**: Make sure your import statement's casings match your project's folder casings.

I came across one other quirk while debugging this same error. I had several providers that were all working, including in showModalBottomSheets, however one was not working. After combing through the entire widget tree, without finding any discrepancies, I found that I had capitalized the first letter of a folder on one of the import statements of my problem-child notifier. I think this confused the compiler and caused it to throw the `Could not find the correct Provider above this widget` error.

After ensuring the import statement casing matched the folder name, my provider problems were resolved. Hopefully this will save someone a headache.

Answer (score -2):

Faced the same issue while dealing with showModelBottomSheet, since it happens to work in a different (context)widget tree I had to level up my state to that of the app so that I could access my provider using the context.

[image: Code snippet]