# How to add provider to second widget tree?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am try follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548225) for add provider to second widget tree (so can call provider from function). But I get error:

> [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Error: Could
>   not find the correct Provider above this
>   Page Widget

For sure I provide `Model2` correct in other widget tree so it have ancestor.

```
Future<void> _neverSatisfied() async {

final model2 = Provider.of<Model2>(context, listen: false);

  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, 
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return 


    Provider.value(value: model2, child:


AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Rewind and remember'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('You will never be satisfied.'),
              Text('You\’re like me. I’m never satisfied.'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Regret'),
            onPressed: () async {
await model2.getData();

              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

First widget in same `StatefulWidget`:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Model1, Model2>(
initialBuilder: (_) => Model2(),
  builder: (_, model1, model2) => model2
    ..string = model1.string,
),
  child: Consumer<Model2>(
    builder: (context, model2, _) =>
```

Second:

```
  @override
  Widget buildStep(BuildContext context) {
  Consumer<Model2>(
    builder: (context, model2, _) =>
...

   _neverSatisfied();
```

Comment: You'll need to use a different context to call Provider.of. One that is a descendant of the provider

Comment: @RémiRousselet You can explain where I put this? Widget where I call `_neverSatisfied();`? In you example (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548225) you put in showDialog

Comment: Yes. The `context` passed to `Provider.of` in `_neverSatisfied` is invalid, because it is an ancestor of the provider you want to obtain.

Comment: @RémiRousselet So I pass `context` as param to `_neverSatisfied`?

Comment: Yes. Any context that is descendant of the provider should do.