# Flutter: Showdialog not able to access the provider from context

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-provider, flutter-state

How to pass the context to the show dialog in flutter.
I am trying to get hold of the provider in the dialog. It's giving me following error. Works fine on the line outside of the dialog body.

**Error:**

> The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Builder(dirty):
> Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Builder Widget

```dart
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<IncomeProvider>(
      create: (context) => IncomeProvider(),
      child: Consumer<IncomeProvider>(
        builder: (context, provider, child) =>
          return Scaffold(
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
              onPressed: () => showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => Center(
                  child: Material(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: Text(context.watch<IncomeProvider>().toString()),  // <--- This line gives error
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
              label: Text(context.watch<IncomeProvider>().toString()), // <--- This is working.
```

Comment: Can you include full [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) widget that will reproduce the same issue?

Comment: Take a look at this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547784/how-to-access-provided-provider-of-value-inside-showmodalbottomsheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are creating your providers, make them **higher** than `MaterialApp` in the `main.dart` file.

For example:

```
void main() {
    runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(    // <--- this is higher
      providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(/* your providers */),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(/* your providers */),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(/* your providers */),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(    // <--- this is MaterialApp
        title: 'Your App title',
        home: YourHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```