# Update state showModalBottomSheet

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want to update a text when a button is clicked inside a Modal Bottom Sheet. All widgets (text, button) are in the bottom sheet. I tried setstate, statefulbuilder but it didn't work.

I tried to use:

[How to update state of...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52414629/how-to-update-state-of-a-modalbottomsheet-in-flutter)

Comment: Please add the code you have so far

Comment: The code you added isn't quite enough to say what the problem is, please just put in the whole widget of the showmodalbottomsheet

Comment: oke I will try to minimalize it

Comment: the button is inside bottomsheet?

Comment: yes the button and the text are inside the bottomsheet

Comment: @KristófKékesi I have added an answer hope this helps!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the same problem I faced when I was working with BottomSheet.

You can scroll down and copy the whole code or read the explanations.

> **The trick here is using a global ScaffoldKey**

---

First Create the scaffold Key:

```
 final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

then Give this key to the Scaffold:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
       .
       .
       .
```

---

For Better Code Readability I created a separate `openBottomSheet` Function and separate `StateFulWidget` class dedicated to the `bottomsheet` and its `widgets`.

---

The `openBottomSheet` function is as follows:
*Note: The `BottomSheetWidget` is the class name for bottomsheet and its widget.*

```
void openBottomSheet() {
    print("Opening bottom Sheet");
    var sheetController = scaffoldKey.currentState
        .showBottomSheet((context) => BottomSheetWidget());
    
    // On Closure of bottom sheet:
    sheetController.closed.then((value) {
      print("Bottom Sheet Closed");
    });
  }
```

---

The BottomSheet class is a `StateFulWidget` class, which has two buttons and the text widget arranged in a column. You can refer the output images to get the idea about the layout.

and **Bottom Sheet Code is as follows:**

```
class BottomSheetWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomSheetWidget({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BottomSheetWidgetState createState() => _BottomSheetWidgetState();
}

class _BottomSheetWidgetState extends State<BottomSheetWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      color: Colors.amber,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(text),
            RaisedButton(
              child: const Text('Change Text'),
              onPressed: () {
                text = ' Hey, The button pressed and changed the text';
                setState(() {});
                print(text);
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Here's the whole code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: MyStateFullWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// The text is defined here.
String text = 'hello, The Button isn\'t pressed!!!';


class MyStateFullWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyStateFullWidgetState createState() => _MyStateFullWidgetState();
}

class _MyStateFullWidgetState extends State<MyStateFullWidget> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  //This will manage opening and closing of the bottom sheet.
  void openBottomSheet() {
    print("Opening bottom Sheet");
    var sheetController = scaffoldKey.currentState
        .showBottomSheet((context) => BottomSheetWidget());
    sheetController.closed.then((value) {
      print("Bottom Sheet Closed");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('showModalBottomSheet'),
          onPressed: () {
            openBottomSheet();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


// All the widgets that should go into the bottom sheet should go here.
class BottomSheetWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomSheetWidget({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BottomSheetWidgetState createState() => _BottomSheetWidgetState();
}

class _BottomSheetWidgetState extends State<BottomSheetWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      color: Colors.amber,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(text),
            RaisedButton(
              child: const Text('Change Text'),
              onPressed: () {
                text = ' Hey, The button pressed and changed the text';
                setState(() {});
                print(text);
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Before pressing the Button Output:**
[image]

**After pressing the Button Output:**
[image]

---

Hope this helps:

Comment: thanks, I don't have much time but I will check this. Thanks for your time