# Unable to reflect updated parent state in showModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I am relatively new to Flutter and while I really like it I'm struggling to find a way to have state values in the parent be updated in `showModalBottomSheet`. I think I understand the issue to be that the values aren't reflecting in `showModalBottomSheet` when they change in the parent because `showModalBottomSheet` doesn't get rebuilt when the state updates.

I am storing `title` and `content` in the parent because I was also hoping to use it for editing as well as creating todos. I figured the `showModalBottomSheet` could be shared for both. I am attaching a picture on the simulator. What I am expecting is that when `title` changes (i.e. is no longer an empty string) then the Add To Do button should become enabled but it currently stays disabled unless I close the modal and re-open it.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. Below is the code in my `main.dart` file which has `showModalBottomSheet` and has the state values that need to be passed down. `NewToDo` contains the text fields in the modal that capture the values and updates the state in `main` accordingly.

** **EDIT** **

I have seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52414629/how-to-update-state-of-a-modalbottomsheet-in-flutter/56972160#56972160) but it doesn't really explain how to pass state from a parent widget down to a `showBottomModalSheet` widget, it just shows how to manage state within a `showBottomModalSheet` widget. My goal is to have the state change from within `main` to be able to be picked within `showBottomModalSheet`.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './todoitem.dart';
import './todolist.dart';
import 'classes/todo.dart';
import './newtodo.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'To Do Homie',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: "It's To Do's My Guy"),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key, 
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String content = '';
  String title = '';
  int maxId = 0;
  ToDo? _todo;
  final titleController = TextEditingController();
  final contentController = TextEditingController();
  List<ToDo> _todos = [];

  void _addTodo(){

    final todo = ToDo ( 
      title: title,
      id: maxId,  
      isDone: false,
      content: content
    );

    if (_todo != null){
      setState(() {
        _todos[_todos.indexOf(_todo!)] = todo;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _todos.add(todo);
      });
    }

    setState(() {
      content = '';
      maxId = maxId++;
      title = '';
      _todo = null;
    });

    contentController.text = '';
    titleController.text = '';
    
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    titleController.addListener(_handleTitleChange);
    contentController.addListener(_handleContentChange);
    futureAlbum = fetchAlbum();
  }

  void _handleTitleChange() {
    setState(() {
      title = titleController.text;
    });
  }

  void _handleContentChange() {
    setState(() {
      content = contentController.text;
    });
  }

  void _editTodo(ToDo todoitem){
    setState(() {
      _todo = todoitem;
      content = todoitem.content;
      title = todoitem.title;
    });
    contentController.text = todoitem.content;
    titleController.text = todoitem.title;
  }

  void _deleteToDo(ToDo todoitem){
    setState(() {
      _todos = List.from(_todos)..removeAt(_todos.indexOf(todoitem));
    });
  }

  void _clear(){
    contentController.text = '';
    titleController.text = '';
    setState(() {
      content = '';
      title = '';
      _todo = null;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView( 
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: ToDoList(_todos, _editTodo, _deleteToDo)
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet<void>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              print(context);
              return Container(child:NewToDo(titleController, contentController, _addTodo, _clear, _todo),);
            });
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**NewToDo.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './classes/todo.dart';

class NewToDo extends StatelessWidget {

  final Function _addTodo;
  final Function _clear;
  final ToDo? _todo;
  final TextEditingController titleController;
  final TextEditingController contentController;

  const NewToDo(this.titleController, this.contentController, this._addTodo, this._clear, this._todo, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
          Column(children: [
              TextField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Title',
                ),
                controller: titleController,
                autofocus: true,
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Details',
                ),
               controller: contentController,
               autofocus: true,
              ),
               ButtonBar(
                  alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: titleController.text.isNotEmpty ? () => _addTodo() : null, 
                      child: Text(_todo != null ? 'Edit To Do' : 'Add To Do'),
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor: titleController.text.isNotEmpty ? MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.deepPurple) : null,
                        overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.purple), 
                      ),
                    ),
                    Visibility (
                      visible: titleController.text.isNotEmpty || contentController.text.isNotEmpty,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () => _clear(), 
                        child: const Text('Clear'),
                      )),
              ])
            ],
          );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, perhaps this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/56972160/11212287

Comment: @AkshayDoshi thanks for the link. I checked that one out before but it doesn't really explain how to pass state values from a parent widget down to `showModalBottomSheet` it just shows how to manage it's own state within it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextControllers are `listenable`. You can just wrap your Column in two `ValueListenable`s (one for each controller) and that will tell that widget to update whenever their values are updated.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ValueListenableBuilder(
  valueListenable: contentController,
  builder: (context, _content, child) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: titleController,
      builder: (context, _title, child) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Title',
              ),
              controller: titleController,
              autofocus: true,
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Details',
              ),
              controller: contentController,
              autofocus: true,
            ),
            ButtonBar(
              alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed:
                      titleController.text.isNotEmpty ? () => _addTodo() : null,
                  child: Text(_todo != null ? 'Edit To Do' : 'Add To Do'),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: titleController.text.isNotEmpty
                        ? MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.deepPurple)
                        : null,
                    overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.purple),
                  ),
                ),
                Visibility(
                  visible: titleController.text.isNotEmpty ||
                      contentController.text.isNotEmpty,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () => _clear(),
                    child: const Text('Clear'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Another more general alternative I can think of is to use `Provider` (or, if you're familiar enough, regular InheritedWidgets) and the pattern suggested in its readme:

```dart
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  ExampleState createState() => ExampleState();
}

class ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  int _count;

  void increment() {
    setState(() {
      _count++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider.value(
      value: _count,
      child: Provider.value(
        value: this,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

where it suggests reading the count like this:

```dart
return Text(context.watch<int>().toString());
```

Except I'm guessing you can just provide the whole state of the widget to descenents by replacing `_count` with `this` to refer to the whole stateful widget. Don't know if this is recommended though.

`ValueListenable`s would be my first choice and then maybe hooks to simplify their use though.

Comment: I ended up going with the `ValueListenableBuilder` option since I tried it first and it worked perfectly. You're a life saver!