# Widget doesn't update when call update() in bottomsheet GetX Library

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

[image]

When click the icons add and remove the item wont update, even though I have called the update() function in controller()

Here's the code I call the Bottomsheet:

```
Get.bottomSheet(VariantBs(cartItems: cartItem));
```

Here's the view of bottom sheet:

```
Row(
                          children: [
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                if (amount == 1) {
                                  _dx.deleteItem(cartItems[i].itemId);
                                } else {
                                  _dx.updateQty(cartItems[i].itemId,
                                      cartItems[i].qty - 1);
                                }
                              },
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.remove_circle,
                                color: AppColor.orange,
                                size: 34,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 14, vertical: 0),
                              child: Text(
                                cartItems[i].qty.toString(),
                                style: AppFont.lexendSemiB14Primary,
                              ),
                            ),
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                _dx.updateQty(
                                    cartItems[i].itemId, cartItems[i].qty + 1);
                               
                              },
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.add_circle,
                                size: 34,
                                color: AppColor.orange,
                              ),
                            ),
                            const Spacer(),
                            Text(() {
                              final fmt = MoneyFormatter(
                                  settings: MoneyFormatterSettings(
                                    thousandSeparator: '.',
                                    decimalSeparator: ',',
                                  ),
                                  amount: double.parse(amount.toString()));
                              return 'Rp${fmt.output.withoutFractionDigits}';
                            }(), style: AppFont.lexendMedium14),
                          ],
                        ),
```

And the function in controller:

```
 updateQty(int itemId, int qty) async {
    final api = await _brofoodRepository.updateQty(itemId, qty);

    return api.fold((error) => Get.snackbar('Terjadi Kesalahan', error.data),
        (response) {
      getCart();
      update();
    });
  }


 getCart() async {
    final api = await _brofoodRepository.getCart();

    return api.fold((error) => Get.snackbar('Terjadi Kesalahan', error.data),
        (response) {
      if (response.merchantName == "") {
        cart.value = Cart();
      } else {
        cart.value = response;
        totalItems.value = 0;
        totalPrice.value = 0;
        for (var element in cart.value.cartItems) {
          totalItems.value += element.qty;
          totalPrice.value += element.price * element.qty;
          if (element.variants == null) {
          } else {
            for (var x in element.variants!) {
              for (var y in x.options) {
                totalPrice.value += y.price * element.qty;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      update();
    });
  }
```

But when i reopen the bottomsheet the new value of item is appeared.

Any ideas of the issues? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `GetBuilder` in order to update the screen:

```
GetBuilder<YourController>(
  builder:(controller)=> Text(
                            controller.cartItems[i].qty.toString(),
                            style: AppFont.lexendSemiB14Primary,
                          ),
)
```

Comment: I have used that as the child of the body of scaffold, so the get builder is the root

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, which is described by Getx's author in the [following issue](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/257#issuecomment-645770399)

> Flutter does not reconstruct all children of a widget, so you have two options:
> 1- Use dropdown outside the modal.
> 2- Encapsulate the widget you want to be changed and not the modal by a GetBuilder.

So I have used `showModalBottomSheet` instead of `Get.bottomSheet` as described in the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56972160/1565971)

```
showModalBottomSheet(
context: context,
builder: (context) {
  return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState /*You can rename this!*/) {
    return Container(
      height: heightOfModalBottomSheet,
      child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          heightOfModalBottomSheet += 10;
        });
      }),
    );
  });
});
```

So I ended up using:

- `setState` for updating the bottomsheet
- `MY_VIEW_CONTROLLER` for updating selected value in the parent view

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Obx()` function in `Get.bottomSheet` to ensure that your variables get updated.

```
Get.bottomSheet(Obx(() => VariantBs(cartItems: cartItem)));
```