# Flutter Modalbottomsheet with ExpansionPanelList and FilterChip

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I want create a filter for my app. I use ModalBottom. The filters are multiple so I use ExpansionPanelList for this. When I open a Expansion I have the list of FilterChip Item.
I have 2 problems :

- When I click in a FilterChip the background not change for see the selection. But my list `tags` and `collections` have the correct value.
- When I close ModalBottomSheet and I reopen this : the filters don't save old value.

Thanks,

```
//in other file : the call of the filters
void _showFilter() async {
    /*data = {"tags":["tag1", "tag2","tag3" ...], 
              "collection": ["coll1","coll2", ...]}*/
    var data = await repository().filter();
    Map<String, dynamic> filters = jsonDecode(data);

    await showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => 
                Filter(title: l10n.filterText, filters: filters));
    setState(() {});
  }

//my file filter
class Filter extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final Map<String, dynamic> filters;

  const Filter({super.key, required this.title, required this.filters});

  @override
  State<Filter> createState() => FilterState();
}

class FilterState extends State<Filter> {
  late Map<String, dynamic> filters;
  static late List<ItemExpansionPanel> _data;
  late List<dynamic> tags;
  var selectedTags = [];
  late List<dynamic> collections;
  var selectedCollections = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    filters = widget.filters;
    tags = filters["tags"]
        .map((option) => {"key": option, "title": option, "value": false})
        .toList();
    collections = filters["collection"]
        .map((option) => {"key": option, "title": option, "value": false})
        .toList();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    _data = generateItems(_buildPanelList());
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(widget.title,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge),
            const SizedBox(height: 8),
            ExpansionPanelList(
              dividerColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              elevation: 2,
              expandedHeaderPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
              expansionCallback: (int item, bool status) {
                setState(() => _data[item].isExpanded = !status);
              },
              children: _data.map<ExpansionPanel>((ItemExpansionPanel item) {
                return ExpansionPanel(
                  canTapOnHeader: true,
                  headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                    return ListTile(title: Text(item.headerValue));
                  },
                  body: item.body,
                  isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _buildPanelList() {
    return filters.keys
        .map((key) =>
            {"title": key, "expandedValue": key, "body": _generateItems(key)})
        .toList();
  }

  Widget _generateItems(String key) {
    List<dynamic> list = [];
    switch (key) {
      case "tags":
        list = tags;
        break;
      case "collection":
        list = collections;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    List<Widget> itemFilters =
        list.asMap().entries.map((item) => _buildChip(item, key)).toList();
    return Wrap(
        alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
        runAlignment: WrapAlignment.start,
        runSpacing: 8,
        spacing: 16,
        children: itemFilters);
  }

  Widget _buildChip(MapEntry<int, dynamic> map, String key) {
    final foregroundColor = map.value['value'] ? Colors.white : Colors.black;
    return FilterChip(
      selected: selectedTags.contains(map.value['title']),
      selectedColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      disabledColor: null,
      shape: StadiumBorder(
          side: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
      labelStyle:
          TextStyle(color: foregroundColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      label: Text(map.value['title']),
      onSelected: (bool value) {
        !selectedTags.contains(map.value['title'])
            ? selectedTags.add(map.value['title'])
            : selectedTags.remove(map.value['title']);
        setState(() => _itemListMaj(key, map.key));
      },
    );
  }

  void _itemListMaj(String key, int index) {
    switch (key) {
      case "tags":
        bool curValue = tags[index]['value'] as bool;
        tags[index].update('value', (value) => !curValue);
        break;
      case "collection":
        bool curValue = collections[index]['value'] as bool;
        collections[index].update('value', (value) => !curValue);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: May the you have to use the statefulBuilder in the parent of that widget.check out this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56972160/12000053

Comment: Thank I have already used `statefulBuilder` in the parent but not work. By the way, I use a class `StatefulWidget` for Filter

Comment: Hey @mollusk so can you post some sample filter data which you fetched over here :  await repository().filter(); So that i can create a example for you.

Comment: Also add the ItemExpansionPanel one

Comment: Thanks I updated the post, how keep safe the value of my list tags and collections between my page and the modalbottomsheet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the first problem. In fact, `didChangeDependencies()` is'nt call in `setState`. So I add the construct panel in the setState.

```
setState(() {
   _itemListMaj(key, map.key);
   _data = generateItems(_buildPanelList());
});
```

I have always the second problem to resolve :

- When I close ModalBottomSheet and I reopen this : the filters don't save old value.

How keep safe the value of my list `tags` and `collections` between my page and the modalbottomsheet ?

Thanks,