# Flutter: I want to change the value of boolean but it is not working for me

Tags: flutter, dart

> Here is the gesture Detector in which I am using setstate inside
> gesture detector and I've applied check on expansion tile:

```
Future<void> showModel(BuildContext context) {
bool openList=false;
return showModalBottomSheet(
context: context,
isScrollControlled: true,
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child:ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [
              GestureDetector(
               onTap: (){
                setState(() {
                 openList=true;
                });
               },
                child: Image.asset('assets/icons/diirection.png', 
                height: Get.height * 0.05)),
          
        openList==false? ExpansionTile(
          tilePadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        title:itemRow(),
        children: [
          itemDetails()
        ],
        ):Text('data'),
       
        ]
      ),
    );
  
  },
);
```

}

> and here the widget which I want to change on tap.

```
openList==false? ExpansionTile(
          tilePadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        title:itemRow(),
        children: [
          itemDetails()
        ],
        ):Text('data'),
```

Comment: Where did you declare openList?

Comment: I am using modal bottom sheet and i have wraped it in future function and after declaring function I have initialized openList=false

Comment: Can you show the modalBottomSheet? It looks like you need wrap your widget inside a StatefulBuilder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52414629/how-to-update-state-of-a-modalbottomsheet-in-flutter

Comment: i've updated my question. i am using stateful class

Comment: See the link, wrap it inside a StatefulBuilder or put your modalBottomSheet content in it's own StatefulWidget

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<void> showModel(BuildContext context) {
bool openList=false;
```

on the second line here, every time the build method is called, that is, as long as the widget exists, openList is being set to false. you should take bool `openLists = false;` **outside** your build method.

Comment: still same issue. when i close modal sheet and open it again then is showing me changes

Comment: how do you call showModel()? Can you show your Stateful Widget where you call it?

Comment: i've call it inside class but my problem has been solve I have wrapped my container in stateful builder and it worked