# Flutter Filter Chip Issues with Bottom Sheet Modal

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I have a bottom list modal in flutter that I want to use as a way to add and remove tags. I am using filter chips as the way to toggle from a pre-built list of tags.

I have the bottom sheet modal working great, pops up on icon button click. The filter chips show in the modal but nothing happens when I tap them... But if I close the bottom sheet modal then re-open it they they look selected...

```
         IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle),
              color: const Color(0xFF20647A),
              //show tags sheeet
              onPressed: () {
                showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.58,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child:
                          //bottom sheet body
                          Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          ElevatedButton(
                            child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 16),
                          Wrap(
                            spacing: 10,
                            children: tagListFull.map(
                              (category) {
                                return FilterChip(
                                  selected:
                                      selectedTags.contains(category),
                                  onSelected: (bool selected) {
                                    if (selected) {
                                      selectedTags.add(category);
                                    } else {
                                      selectedTags.remove(category);
                                    }
                                  },
                                  label: Text(category),
                                );
                              },
                            ).toList(),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
```

My initial gut was that it was a setState issue, but when I added set state to the add(category) and remove(category) then taping them didnt work at all even when closing and re-openning the bottom sheet modal.

Comment: I could be wrong, but i think modalBottomSheets specifically are stateless, whereas the option is Stateful. I think i experienced something similar.

Comment: oooo interesting. I may have to try this out later then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52414629/how-to-update-state-of-a-modalbottomsheet-in-flutter

Comment: ah yeah that answer in that link with the StatefulBuilder inside the modal, would work perfectly for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modal bottom sheet itself is not stateful, the widget that shows the modal bottom sheet is. Therefore, when you call `setState`, the modal bottom sheet knows nothing about what just happened.

The reason that closing the modal bottom sheet and re-opening then shows the updated state is because when the modal bottom sheet is re-opened (i.e. built), it simply accesses the current state, which was modified since the last time the modal bottom sheet was built through a call to `showModalBottomSheet`.

You can solve this in numerous ways. I'll show you an approach that allows the modal bottom sheet filter chips to change their state.

You can implement a stateful widget that rebuilds the `FilterChip` on tap:

```
class MyFilterChip extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyFilterChip({super.key, required this.onChanged});

  final void Function(bool) onChanged;

  @override
  State<MyFilterChip> createState() => MyFilterChipState();
}

class MyFilterChipState extends State<MyFilterChip> {
  bool _selected = false;
  bool get selected => _selected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FilterChip(
      label: const Text("filter 1"),
      selected: _selected,
      onSelected: (value) {
        setState(() => _selected = value);
        widget.onChanged(value);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

You can use the `onChanged` callback from to update your `selectedTags`. There are other approaches such as notifiers, but this one is simple.

You would simply replace your `FilterChip` widgets with `MyFilterChip` widgets:

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 200.0,
        child: MyFilterChip(
          onChanged: (isSelected) {
            if (selected) {
              selectedTags.add(category);
            } else {
              selectedTags.remove(category);
            }
          },
        ),
      );
    },
  );
```