# Determining if widget is in the foreground/background

Tags: flutter, dart

Say I have a Flutter app with two screens - screen `A` and screen `B`. Screen `A` is just a `ListView` that displays a list of items but needs to perform a network call whenever the list changes and then update the list. Screen `B` can modify the list of items but I want screen `A` to only perform the network call when screen `A` is in the foreground and being displayed. As far as I can tell, I cannot do this easily. Screen `A` is not disposed and reinitialized when navigating to and from screen `B`. It would very helpful if `StatefulWidget` had `onForeground` and `onBackground` methods to override, but they do not. This problem is not exclusive to navigation either, but this same problem presents itself when using `PageView` with full-screen pages. Is there some proper/standard way of implementing this?

My current setup is as follows: I let the parent widget to both screen `A` and `B` hold the list in a `ValueNotifier` and pass it to both screens when constructing them. Then, screen `A` listens for changes on the `ValueNotifier` and performs a network call whenever it does. So, in order to determine whether screen `A` is in the foreground/background, I will have to start/stop listening for changes before/after navigating. But I haven't started implementing this, as I think it will get complicated when widgets far down the widget tree trigger the navigation or other widgets need to know whether they're in the foreground/background.

Another option I've thought of is instead of observing for changes in the list, I could rather just return a result from screen `B` saying whether or not the list changed and react then. But I can think of many ways this can complicate my code as well since my real app involves more than just one dependency. I would have to create a custom result class for each screen containing a record of all the data that changed then it would be tedious if I want to add more data in the future. And how would I handle navigation to screen `B` then screen `C`? The result would have to be retained and passed down so screen `A` can react to changes made by screen `C`. I would also have to ensure all calls to `Navigator.pop` contained the result, and override back button presses to `pop` with the result. And I'd also have to ensure that the result makes it to the proper widgets that need to react to changes.

Am I just missing something simple to accomplish this? I am not the most experienced with Flutter and I wouldn't be surprised if there's some easy solution I haven't learned yet.

**Edit:** After some more testing, it appears `AnimationController` does something similar to what I need with the `vsync` parameter, in that it does not update when the `State` is in the background or when it is not being drawn. So, I could use `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` on screen `A`'s state, then use `createTicker` to create a `Ticker`, and then check if the `Ticker.isTicking` whenever the list changes. If it is ticking, screen `A` is in the foreground, otherwise it is in the background. Although I'm not sure if this is a good approach, since it appears `Ticker`'s are really only used for `Animation`s and there's nothing documented for a use case like mine.

Comment: call **A**(parent) From **B**(child) and force it to refresh [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51778268/4879683)

Comment: That's not what I want to do. I do not want to refresh screen `A` (or perform the network call) when screen `B` is in the foreground.

Comment: yes this work , that how i do it in my app ?

Comment: here an examble [e004_flutter_listview_crud_app_using_nonsecure_rest_api/main.dart at master · elrashid-flutter-examples/e004_flutter_listview_crud_app_using_nonsecure_rest_api](https://github.com/elrashid-flutter-examples/e004_flutter_listview_crud_app_using_nonsecure_rest_api/blob/master/lib/main.dart)

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. But that's basically the same as returning a result from screen `B`. It would work for apps with a simple widget tree and with a few screens like in your example, but will get more complicated when you add widgets that initiate navigation or have more screens. In your example, if `TaskAddPageWidget` navigated to another screen which modified the tasks, you have to ensure `TasksPageWidget` calls `refresh` only when both screens are finished. It would be a lot easier to observe the tasks, and only `refresh` when the tasks change and the list is in the foreground.

Comment: ☺your are wright ✔ , did you consider using ***package:provider*** it will make you like easier for complex app with shared state