# Expose data from stateful widget? flutter

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget

I have a Tinderlike card deck. I'm trying to get the front card of the deck from outside the Tinderlike widget (`Stateful`).

When I try to expose his state using [controlling state from outside of a StatefulWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46057353/controlling-state-from-outside-of-a-statefulwidget)

I always get a `null`. My TinderLike widget is inside a `StatelessWidget`.
Is there a better way to expose data from a `StatefulWidget` to its parents?

Comment: What do you mean by "always null"?

Comment: when im invoking using TinderLike.of(context).getFrontCard() a NoSuchMethodError: The method 'getFrontCard' was called on null is always thrown

Comment: Could you provide the codes you're using?

Comment: its a part of a big project so it will be problematic :(