# Accessing members of a stateful widget in a pageview

Tags: flutter

I have a screen in my Flutter app that contains a pageview. In that pageview are four stateful widgets. I need to be able to access the members of the first three widgets so I can get the data from them, bring it into the main screen class, and send it to the fourth widget. Below is a model of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image: Model]

I'm thinking that I can do this with methods in each widget's state class but when I create a method there, I can't access it anywhere else even if it's public.

An example of one of the widgets:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WidgetSample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WidgetSampleState createState() => _WidgetSampleState();
}

class _WidgetSampleState extends State<WidgetSample> {
  TextEditingController _sampleController = new TextEditingController();

  //I want to access this method through an instance of the WidgetSample class
  String getTextFromField(){
    return _sampleController.text;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: TextField(
        controller: _sampleController,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried creating a copy of the method in the widget sample class that calls the method in the state class but that hasn't worked.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Place the getTextFromField() method outside the class to make it global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I have found an answer to my problem provided by BambinoUA on this post:

[Controlling State from outside of a StatefulWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46057353/controlling-state-from-outside-of-a-statefulwidget)